# DRYing up scoped routes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, routes

In my Rails 4 app I have the following route:

```
scope ':section' do
  resources :articles
  resources :features
  resources :galleries
end
```

The section is set in the application controller:

```
@current_section = params[:section]
```

In my views, I am linking to pages using articles(@channel), article_path(@channel, article). It works but I have the feeling it could be DRYer. Is there a way that, once set, :section becomes implicit for all path helpers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
def default_url_options
  { section: @current_section }
end
```

in `ApplicationController`?

cf. http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#default-url-options